# What do I need to do if I have received a tax refund before I have submitted an amended return?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, amended-tax-return

I am preparing to send in an amended return today to both state and federal entities. Nothing big just forgot to add a 1099 which barely crosses the threshold for reporting.

I had already submitted my returns last month and got a refund from both fed and state deposited into my account which I have been holding.

With my amendment I will still get a refund for both but for obviously less money.

How is this process handled?
Do I need to mail checks for the estimated difference with the amendment?
Do I wait for a bill from the IRS?
Will they take the money out of my account and adjust the difference?

I have no experience with this but I would like to know what to expect and the best way to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you already got the refund, this is a standard 1040X situation. No definitely don't wait until the IRS bills you, they won't send you a letter on it until it's after the filing deadline when you could owe penalties and interest.

When you complete the 1040X you'll have an amount on line 20 that you owe. You can pay that by a variety of methods, including a check, online, etc. The IRS encourages you to pay by a method other than check.
https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040x#idm139749433899104
Then mail your 1040X either with a check or pay online at:
https://www.irs.gov/payments

We can't give you an answer about your state because you didn't tell us what state, but it's likely to be very similar to the federal.

Comment: Thanks but even with the amendment I still wouldn't owe anything. Do I just calculate the different between my initial refund and this estimated refund and pay online? I live in Washington D.C. and I think they have a pay online method

Comment: You wouldn't have owed, but now that they've sent you the refund it's your money. Now with the corrected amounts you owe whatever difference there is. Yes, look at the 1040X. It calculates the difference and the amount you owe back and you can pay that online.

Comment: I have no experience with DC taxes but the instructions for the D-40 and D-40EZ say "To file an amended return for the current year, complete another 2018 DC Individual Income Tax Return and fill in the "amended return" oval on the form.  Attach a list with explanations of the changes covered by your amended return." https://otr.cfo.dc.gov/sites/default/files/dc/sites/otr/publication/attachments/2018%20D-40%20BOOK%20WEBSITE%20REV_02.13.2019_ReducedSize.pdf  Also, yes, it looks like you can pay DC tax online.

Comment: If this is from a previous year's return, then the OP probably already owes at the very least interest if not penalties. How does one go about figuring out what one currently owes, taking the possibility of interest and penalties into account?